# Is there any alternative to PHP Tokenizer that is able to parse OOP code?

Tags: php, oop

I am looking for a parser similar to PHP's Tokenizer but that can tokenize object oriented code.

When I try to tokenize this code:

```
$db->delete_query(
    "sessions",
    "ip='".$db->escape_string($session->ipaddress)."'"
);
```

(from MyBB) with `token_get_all()` all I get is:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    int(311)
    [1]=>
    string(82) "$db->delete_query("sessions", "ip='".$db->escape_string($session->ipaddress)."'");"
    [2]=>
    int(1)
  }
}
```

I would like to know if I can get this code properly tokenized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tokenizer works with valid PHP sources and those start with `<?php`, so you should call `token_get_all()` like this:

```
$tokens = token_get_all('<?php your code here');
```